# Test case null time exception

Tags: java, junit

I am having trouble with writing JUnit test for this case. I get runtime error.
I tried

```
import junit.framework.*;
import student.TestCase;

public class MemmanTest extends TestCase {

public MemmanTest() {
    // empty
}

public void testMemmanSystemIn() throws Exception {

    setSystemIn("10 32 P1sampleInput.txt");
    Memman.main(null);
    assertTrue(systemOut().getHistory(), "P1sampleOutput.txt");
    }
}`
```

So I can check the input file and the output file is same. (actually when I run the acutal program, its same, but I just cannot make the test case.)

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you get a runtime error? You're passing null and trying to call `length` on it.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you call main.

If you don't specify any arguments, the args variable is not null; it's an empty array.

```
Memman.main(new String[]{});
```

You could also use varargs instead of an array, then just call main with no arguments.

Edit: As Holger pointed out, it looks like you're trying to use setSystemIn() to pass arguments into the main() method. That won't work. Instead, you should just pass them into the array:

```
Memman.main(new String[]{"10", "32", "P1sampleInput.txt"});
```

This is the first result for googling "junit pass arguments to main": [Passing command line arguments to JUnit in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208415/passing-command-line-arguments-to-junit-in-eclipse)

Comment: You can most certainly pass `null` to `main`.  It's just not *advisable*.

Comment: Sure, you *can* pass null. But that's not what Java passes in when main() is called automatically, so it's not what you should pass when writing test cases.

Comment: While this solves the `NullpointerException` pessing an empty array will obviously not solve the problem that the questioner is providing the arguments as System.in contents instead of arguments to `main` as expected by the code under test.